# How to use Material design ProgressBar on pre Lollipop devices?

Tags: android, material-design

Material design progress bar looks cool, but I can't use it on pre Lollipop devices. Any one know any way to do that?

Comment: i think you have to write your own style for the progress bar with the same color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am late this is how you can do it.

Do this in your drawable folder make a file `progress_animator` with the contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--<layer-list>-->
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="1080">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:fromDegrees="-90"
                android:toDegrees="-90">
                <shape
                    android:innerRadiusRatio="3.0"
                    android:shape="ring"
                    android:thickness="2.5dp"
                    android:useLevel="true">

                    <gradient
                        android:angle="0"
                        android:endColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:startColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:type="sweep"
                        android:useLevel="false" />
                </shape>
            </rotate>
        </item>

    </layer-list>
</rotate>
```

In your layout now you will have to add in ProgressBar as an indeterminate progress drawable:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBarPreview"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_animator"
    />
```